# Find records within date range

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I set a search_start_date and a search_end_date and then I want to find records which fall into this time range. But I get nothing back using the code below. What should I change to make this work?

```
 search_start_date = "01-01-2013"
 search_end_date = "01-12-2013"
 @activities = @employee.activities
 projects = @activities.where("start_date >= ? and end_date =< ?", search_start_date, search_end_date)
```

Edit: I now use `search_start_date = DateTime.new(2013, 1, 1)`, which seems to work.

Comment: What type is those field in the database ?

Comment: What is the type of `start_date` and `end_date`?

Comment: paste code by which u r getting @activities

Comment: seems like there is a problem in the date format and also @activity is not a model if it is a scoped from Activity model then it may work else it can not work

Comment: start_date and end_date are of type Datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just modifying the @derekyau solution:-

```
search_start_date = "01-01-2013".to_date
 search_end_date = "01-12-2013".to_date
 projects = @activities.where("start_date >= ? and end_date =< ?", search_start_date, search_end_date)
```

Edit: I now use `search_start_date = DateTime.new(2013, 1, 1)`, which seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

The Dates you are using are ambiguous. It is not clear if it's MM-DD-YYYY or DD-MM-YYYY. Depending on the region where you live, both could be correct. Use the default ruby unambiguous formatting YYYY-MM-DD or even better, use actual date objects.

You can also parse your strings to dates like in the example below. I also corrected the second compare operator to make it more concise. I'm unsure if both would have worked anyway. And don't forget the `.all` in case you didn't just leave it out of your querstion on purpose.

```
search_start_date = Date.strptime("01-01-2013", "%d-%m-%Y")
search_end_date   = Date.strptime("01-12-2013", "%d-%m-%Y")

projects = @activities.where("start_date >= ? and end_date <= ?", search_start_date, search_end_date).all
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to feed "Date" or "Time" objects into the ActiveRecord query, try something like this:

```
 search_start_date = Date.parse("01-01-2013")
 search_end_date = Date.parse("01-12-2013")
 projects = @activities.where("start_date >= ? and end_date =< ?", search_start_date, search_end_date)
```

Comment: Then I get this erorr: PG::Error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone =< unknown
LINE 1: ...= $1 AND (start_date >= '2013-01-01' and end_date =< '2013-1...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Sorry I just realized you were performing this on @activities, what type of variable is that? Perhaps you want to do the .where on the model itself. (Ice. Activity.where ...)

Comment: @activities are model records for a certain employee, like: Employee.first.activities

Comment: Can you update the question to show how you are setting the variable @activities?

Comment: Done. Although in real code this is done in the controller, but for now it clarifies the above code